# Horizontally unaligned divs in IE9 while fine on FF/IE8/Chrome/Opera/Safari

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, alignment

Good day everyone, I'm having trouble with IE9 today, everything else works but IE9 (and possibly IE10, no machine to test)

Here's the code: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qGPrB/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<head>
    <title>Titre</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .carouselNav {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 9998;
            top: 92px;
            right: 300px;
            width:100px;
        }
        .carouselNav div {
            padding:10px;
            display:inline;
        }
        .carouselNav span {
            padding-right:15px;
        }
        .carousel {
            position:relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="carousel" style="overflow: visible;">
        <div class="carouselMedia"> <a href="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/fr/solutions.php?solution=phone_ip"><img id="carousel_img_item_1" src="http://achatplus.com/static/template/style1/img/header/slide1_phone_ip_fr.jpg" alt=""/></a>

            <a
            href="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/fr/solutions.php?solution=mobility">
                <img id="carousel_img_item_2" style="display: none;" src="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/static/template/style1/img/header/slide2_mobility_fr.jpg"
                alt="" />
                </a> <a href="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/fr/solutions.php?solution=shipping"><img id="carousel_img_item_3"  style="display: none;" src="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/static/template/style1/img/header/slide3_shipping_fr.jpg" alt=""/></a>

                <a
                href="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/fr/solutions.php?solution=office">
                    <img id="carousel_img_item_4" style="display: none;" src="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/static/template/style1/img/header/slide4_office_fr.jpg"
                    alt="" />
                    </a> <a href="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/fr/solutions.php?solution=internet"><img id="carousel_img_item_5" style="display: none;" src="http://extranet.achaplus.local/~apouliot_site_1284/static/template/style1/img/header/slide5_internet_fr.jpg"alt=""/></a>

        </div>
        <div class="carouselNav">
            <div id="item_1" title="1" class=""></div>
            <div id="item_2" title="2" class=""></div>
            <div id="item_3" title="3" class=""></div>
            <div id="item_4" title="4" class=""></div>
            <div id="item_5" title="5" class=""></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ok so there is an image and there are 5 divs aligned over the 5 buttons (the active one is green)

Each div is supposed to be empty so I used a padding of 10px to make 20x20 divs (bonus points if you find why it's 20x38).
The surrounding div is 100px wide.

In every browser but IE9, the divs are perfectly fine. However on IE9 the main div is about 14px too high.

I ran out of ideas of what the problem might be a long while ago.

Every bit of help and suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using position:absolute on the divs.

That caused ie to not take the clicks on the divs unless there was something in it so I put an   with a font-size:100px; so that it fills the div.

Answer (score 0):

They look fine to me in IE9 and IE10, but I would suggest using `width:20px;height:20px;display:inline-block` rather than your `padding:10px` trick.

Comment: are they as centered as on chrome? edit/ I mean the bottom of the div shouldn't be on the bottom of the button it should be a bit more down.

Comment: Yes they are. However keep in mind that jsFiddle may be causing or fixing some problems because you basically have two `<!DOCTYPE>` tags (one from the wrapper, one from your content)

Comment: I did use inline-block before the padding, however the inline-block creates a space between the different divs. Also I read that inline-block does not have perfect compatibility with IE

Comment: Inline-block requires you to jump through a few hoops if you're targeting IE7 or older.  Otherwise, it works fine IE8+

Comment: @cimmanon I see, thanks for the clarification. However unless there's a trick so it doesn't create a space between the divs then I can't use that..

Comment: There's only space there because of the space in the HTML source. Remove the newlines between the `<div>` tags and it'll work fine.

Comment: You are right, removing the new lines between the divs did work, it just makes the code a bit ugly though. Noted nonetheless. Edit: I just checked on IE if it changed something and it did, it is now horizontally aligned, however it is now vertically unaligned by about 20px...